# Get max value per day with the corresponding name

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following table:

| day | name | val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12-01-2021 | Een | 1 |
| 11-01-2021 | Twee | 12 |
| 12-01-2021 | Drie | 0 |
| 12-01-2021 | Twee | 1 |
| 11-01-2021 | Drie | 19 |
| 11-01-2021 | Een | 11 |

Now I want to get the max `val` per day, including the name of the corresponding `val`. How can I get this? I got to the following query:

```
select max(val), day 
from table t 
group by day;
```

However, I want the result to include the corresponding name. My first idea was to include `name` in the query:

```
select name, max(val), day 
from table t 
group by day;
```

The problem is that Postgres wants me to also group by name, which again results in the table above (in a different order of rows).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (day) t.*
from t
order by day, val desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a WINDOW function, to avoid DISTINCT ON and make work on other brands of databases as well. The row_number() and the ORDER BY will do the trick:

```
WITH i AS (
    SELECT  
        name
        , val
        , day
        , row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY val DESC, day)
    FROM    table t
)
SELECT  name
    ,   val
    ,   day
FROM    i
WHERE   row_number = 1; -- one result for every name, the first one
```

Answer (score 0):

you try below sql.

```
WITH max_val AS (
    SELECT MAX(val) AS max_val
           ,day 
    FROM TABLE t
    GROUP BY day
)

SELECT  max_val.max_val
        ,t.name
        ,t.day
FROM TABLE t
INNER JOIN max_val
ON t.day = max_val.day
;
```